# How can I specify a general (x,y) position in Python lists?

Tags: python, arrays, list, indexing, maze

I have to make a maze game with a matrix as the maze. I want to be able to move the player (X) up/down/right/left. To do this I have to define the coordinates x,y of the array in order to move them around accordingly. How can I specify a general position in the array?

This is my maze ("1" represents a wall, and "X" is the player):

```
level = [
    ["1","X","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1"],
    ["1"," "," ","1","1","1","1","1","1","1"," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," ","1","1","1","1","1"],
    ["1"," "," ","1","1","1","1","1","1","1"," "," ","1","1","1","1","1","1"," "," ","1","1","1","1","1"],
    ["1"," "," "," "," "," "," "," ","1","1"," "," ","1","1","1","1","1","1"," "," ","1","1","1","1","1"],
    ["1"," "," "," "," "," "," "," ","1","1"," "," ","1","1","1"," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," ","1","1"],
    ["1"," ","1","1","1","1"," "," ","1","1"," "," ","1","1","1"," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," ","1","1"],
    ["1"," ","1","1","1","1"," "," ","1","1"," "," ","1","1","1","1","1","1"," "," ","1","1","1","1","1"],
    ["1"," ","1","1","1","1"," "," ","1","1"," "," "," "," ","1","1","1","1"," "," ","1","1","1","1","1"],
    ["1"," "," ","1","1","1"," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," ","1","1","1","1"," "," "," "," "," "," ","1"],
    ["1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1"," ","1"]
]

start_maze = level[0][1]
end_maze = level[9][23]
print(start_maze)
print(end_maze)

for bla in level:
    print(' '.join(str(n) for n in bla))
```

So the output of the maze is:
[Maze](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGSMp.png)

What I want to do is to be able to say player is in position "bla". If the player chooses to move up that means the position now becomes -1 in the x direction and stays the same in the y direction....I hope I'm clear enough..I'm new to Python. (Using Python 3 btw)

This is what I tried originally but it didn't work (This is for moving up):

```
 #--MOVE = UP--
    if move == "UP":
        print(move)
        for y in range(0,len(level)):
            for x in range(0,len(level[y])):
                if level[y][x] == " ":
                    level[y][x] = level[y-1][x]
                    level[y][x] = "X"
                    print(level)
                else:
                    print('Oups - there is a wall there.')
                    try_again = input('Try Again? Y for Yes, N for No: ')
                    try_again = try_again.upper()
                    if try_again == 'Y':
                        continue           
                    else:
                        start = False       #to exit the loop and quit the program
```

Comment: I'm not clear what you're asking since you already appear to be aware of how to index nested lists. `bla = level[9][23]`?

Comment: Yeah I know how to index..My question is, can I specify a general (x,y) position in my array which can be updated each time the player moves (by +/- 1)?

Comment: Yes... by indexing. That's the part I'm not following. A 2D index _is_ where a player currently is in your maze, and you just need to add/subtract 1 in the (x, y) coords when they make a move.

Comment: @MOA Include what you have tried in your question, not in a comment, and describe how it didn't work.

Comment: Please [edit] your original post to show that so we can see it formatted correctly

Comment: Ok, well `move[y][x] = level[1][1]` is an error right away because we know that `move` is a string that must be equal to `"UP"`. It is not a reference to your maze.

Comment: Mmmm, ok, it seems you changed the code :)

Comment: Yeah sorry that was a previous version. It is the latest version now

Comment: that's not an array, is a list of lists

Comment: True, but doesn't indexing work in the same way?

Comment: @MOA "array" in Python is almost always taken to refer to NumPy arrays, which have very different indexing methods. There is an `array` object in Python too, but I've never actually seen it used in the wild. The distinction isn't really relevant to the problem since we can see the structure, but as an aside it might be interesting for you to know that

Comment: Thank you! I tried it with an np.array but I realised it wasn't necessary, I could just use lists

Comment: What I think the problem is is the for loop. I don't think it's necessary but I can't see another way to specify x and y

Comment: You need to keep the player's position in a separate variable.

Comment: How do i do that so that it is a general player = level[x][y]... How do I define x, y so that they can be changed with each move?

Comment: I'm working on an answer but there's quite a bit of infrastructure to put in place and I'm also trying to sort something else out at the same time :) I will hopefully have a demo soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem, you really need to be keeping the coordinates of the player's location in a variable. You are correct that your `for` loops are unnecessary. Here is one way to make this work, hopefully the comments will help you understand. It can probably be made smoother but should cover the majority of functionality you need.

```
level = [
    ["1"," ","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1"],
    ["1"," "," ","1","1","1","1","1","1","1"," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," ","1","1","1","1","1"],
    ["1"," "," ","1","1","1","1","1","1","1"," "," ","1","1","1","1","1","1"," "," ","1","1","1","1","1"],
    ["1"," "," "," "," "," "," "," ","1","1"," "," ","1","1","1","1","1","1"," "," ","1","1","1","1","1"],
    ["1"," "," "," "," "," "," "," ","1","1"," "," ","1","1","1"," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," ","1","1"],
    ["1"," ","1","1","1","1"," "," ","1","1"," "," ","1","1","1"," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," ","1","1"],
    ["1"," ","1","1","1","1"," "," ","1","1"," "," ","1","1","1","1","1","1"," "," ","1","1","1","1","1"],
    ["1"," ","1","1","1","1"," "," ","1","1"," "," "," "," ","1","1","1","1"," "," ","1","1","1","1","1"],
    ["1"," "," ","1","1","1"," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," ","1","1","1","1"," "," "," "," "," "," ","1"],
    ["1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1"," ","1"]
]

def print_level(level):
    """ Print level row-wise so that it retains its 2D shape """
    for row in level:
        print(row)

# Object to store the player coords
player = {'y': 0, 'x': 1}
level[player['y']][player['x']] = 'X'
print_level(level)

# Translate keywords into coordinate changes
move_modifications = {'UP': {'y': -1, 'x': 0},
                      'DOWN': {'y': 1, 'x': 0},
                      'LEFT': {'y':0, 'x': -1},
                      'RIGHT': {'y': 0, 'x': 1}}

# Main game loop
while True:
    move = input("Which direction?")

    # Give them the option to quit
    if move.lower() == 'exit':
        break

    if not move_modifications.get(move):
        print("Invalid input")
        continue

    coords = move_modifications[move]

    new_y = player['y'] + coords['y']
    new_x = player['x'] + coords['x']

    # Catch them if they try to leave the map
    try:
        maze_position = level[new_y][new_x]
    except IndexError:
        print("Not on map")
        continue

    if maze_position != '1':
        # Move on the map
        level[player['y']][player['x']] = ' '
        level[new_y][new_x] = 'X'

        # Update player coords
        player['y'] = new_y
        player['x'] = new_x

        # Print result
        print_level(level)
    else:
        print("Oops, there's a wall")
```

If you only want to print the area around the player, then you might use something like the following function making use of list slicing. This is just an example approach that you can use as a starting basis.

```
def print_window(level, player_y, player_x, window_size=2):
    """ Print only the immediate surroundings of the player """
    min_y = max(0, player_y - window_size)
    max_y = min(len(level), player_y + window_size)

    min_x = max(0, player_x - window_size)
    max_x = min(len(level[0]), player_x + window_size)

    for row in level[min_y:max_y]:
        print(row[min_x:max_x])
```

Comment: @MOA you're welcome. More importantly, do you follow _how_ it works? I assumed you would be comfortable with dictionaries since you can do 2D indexing. Also, if you think that this has solved your issue, please consider [accepting it as the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) to signify to others than the problem is solved.

Comment: This is an extra thing, but could there be a way to not show the whole maze to the player so that it's not as easy to solve?

Comment: Yeah, I can understand everything - I just would not have been able to think of it on my own. But that will take time and practice!

Comment: @MOA If I get chance I will modify the maze print. And yes, I thought it was easier just to put it together for you rather than trying to convey the approach

Comment: @MOA edited. The window will change size slightly as the player moves around but I don't have time currently to make sure it's always perfectly consistent whilst not throwing errors. It illustrates the approach though.